# SQL Compare INT to GETDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I'm having trouble figuring this out and have tried everything on here. I know it's simple...

Our dates are stored as int in the table. EX 20130409. How do I get SQL to return dates that are less than today's date?

I've been using different combinations of cast and convert but keep getting either overflow errors or conversion failed.

Here is some recent code:

```
SELECT
DBO.SPSYS07.LOC_CODE,
CONVERT(DATETIME,CAST(DBO.SPSYS07.REQ_D_DATE AS CHAR(8)),101) AS [CONVERTED_REQ_DATE],
DBO.SPSYS07.REQ_D_DATE
FROM  DBO.SPSYS07
WHERE SPSYS07.SHIP_DATE <= convert(int,convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112))
```

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: Format __101__ is very different from __112__... is it working if you comment out `convert` in select list?

Comment: are you working with java/c# ? you could code the conversion instead..

Comment: It's MS SQL Server 2008. It does run if I remove the convert in select list.

Comment: And if you replace 101 with 112?

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring today's date and using that

```
Declare todaysDate date
Set todaysDate = getdate()
```

Then convert todaysDate to a string, then remove '-' between year, month and days, and then....

```
Select..... Where shipdate <= todaysDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the '20130101' for your int value.

```
DECLARE @date date
SELECT  @date = CONVERT(date, CAST('20130101' AS CHAR(12)), 112)
SELECT * FROM yourTable where @date < getdate()
```

regards

Comment: That tells me the Select statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations...